# MariaDB 10.2.19 on Linux - Performance very slow

Tags: linux, performance, mariadb

Main issue -  I have a query joining two tables that are indexed..  When I run the query, even after five hours, it's still running..   I've never gotten results back.  it's like a never ending query.
This is a new database that we just installed and really the first query we have tried.  Performance is very slow..  At this point, I'm trying to figure 
out if the issue is the SERVER/CPU/Network/IO/RAM or the database itself (need to tune configuration file) or if it's the query.  When I do explain plan, 
I do see indexes being used.  Is my volume of data too big for MariaDB to handle based on the numbers presented below?  Where do I begin to troubleshoot?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Specs -

•   We have MariaDB 10.2.19 on linux rhel7.5
•   Our database is mainly used to store monthly data and then we report on it and do analytic work.
•   We have around 70 plus tables.
•   3-4 users
•   I am running a query that joins two tables.  The size of the tables are listed below.  The query is not complicated – a simple Inner join on columns and for both tables I am looking for data from the year/month of 201911.  The two tables are joined by two columns and both columns are indexed on both tables.  I have modified the query to many variation and none of the queries return any rows…  even after running for 5 hours, it’s still never finished and I had to kill the query.

Size of (Innodb) Database                           1919.69G

Size of table1   -    daily_2019
                   Total Rows                                            1,034,987,628
                   Data I’m analyzing (using where clause)               73,895,929
                   Total table size                                      230.62GB

Size of table2  -     ZIPCODES

```
                   Total Rows                                            68,429,146                
                   Data I’m analyzing (using where clause)               3,998,975
                   Total table size                                      28.70GB
```

Explain plan -  Tables daily_2019 and zipcodes each have 3 indexes on three different fields.  Col1, col2 and col3 each have indexes both for daily_2019 and zipcodes.  Two keys are used in the explain plan.  One from each table.

We have set the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 128G

**Explain Plan**

```
+------+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------+---------+------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                       | key         | key_len | ref                   | rows    | Extra
+------+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------+---------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | T2    | ref  | ZIP_I2,ZIP_I1,ZIP_I3                | ZIP_I1      | 5       | const                 | 7994358 | Using where
|    1 | SIMPLE      | T1    | ref  | ADHOC_I2,ADHOC_I1,ADHOC_I3          | ADHOC_I3    | 13      | T2.ID                 |      12 | Using index condition; Using where
+------+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------+---------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to share output  from `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Hi sorry I’m new to this forum.  I have the explain plan in a file but don’t see an option to do an attachment.  Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Hi Georg, I added explain plan to my question.  Please let me know if you need anything else.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide the `SELECT` in question and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the two tables.

Comment: @SSN01 Any chance you could post in your original question your SELECT .... and SHOW CREATE TABLE t1; and t2; ?  Someone will be able to assist if you would post this information requested a few days ago.

Comment: Please also post results from linux of TOP or HTOP and we will know how much RAM is available on your MariaDB server.

Comment: @SSN01 Your posted EXPLAIN indicates ~ 8 million rows were read to try to complete the query.  If we could see the information requested Feb 13, we could try to analyze your problem.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.